# List AdapterView onItemClick is not triggering

Tags: android, listview, android-adapterview, onitemclick

In the ListView `onItemLongClick` is getting Triggered but `onItemClick` is not getting triggered. I want both `onItemClick` and `onItemLongClick` to trigger.

`onItemClick` will call item detail activity

`onItemLongClick` will favorite the item

Here is my code:

```
public class myClass extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener ,OnItemLongClickListener


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Boy in onCreateView>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.boy, container, false);
        lvBNames = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);


        searchView = (SearchView) v.findViewById(R.id.action_search);

        if (searchView == null )
        {
            //System.out.println("Unable to instantiate");
        }



        pop_data();
        adapter = new ListBNamesAdapter(getActivity(),mBNamesList);
        lvBNames.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(false); //android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        lvBNames.setAdapter(adapter);
        //lvBNames.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        //lvBNames.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

        //////////////////////////////////////// Test 28 Feb 17
        /// onItemClick is not triggering ............!
        lvBNames.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


/// setOnItemLongClickListener is triggering ............! :)
            lvBNames.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Long Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });

            lvBNames.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            return v;
        }
```

Any Sample program will be appreciated

Comment: Can you show us your adapter? Maybe You have `onClick` on some view in adapter and it cannot dispatch onclick to the next views

Comment: I don't understand why you're implementing OnItemClickListener and not adding your code inside your overriden function.

Comment: planning to implement code in both event different action, ut only long click event is getting triggered

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any layout inside the list view then use ...

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Must be applied to first parent in the list. It will render click to the list items.

Comment: I added to the item_list.xml , not working only long click triggering, even commented LongclickListener, single click is not triggering :-(

Answer (score 0):

try to return `false` in onItemLongClick instead of `true`

Comment: This is an issue only working in one way. If you LongClick something you're triggering the normal click but if you click something you're not triggering the long click.